# Set a minimum value for randomly generated numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I am using this function to generate and alternate random values inside a div

```js
var change_price = $('#myprice');
animationTimer = setInterval(function() {
  change_price.text( ''+   Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) );      
}, 1000);
```

```css
#myprice {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size:24px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myprice">50</div>
```

What I want to do is to control the min value too. 
For example, to have random generated values from 50 to 100.
**Not starting from zero(0) as other posts do**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_number_between_two_values

Comment: @Mohammad I want to control the minimum value. The answer you posted is about to generate random number too, but with no minimum limit. values there starting from 0

Comment: @Bill Promlem fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [mozilla developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values_inclusive) you can generate random number between `max` and `min` as shown in bottom

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

So your code should changed to

```js
var change_price = $('#myprice');
animationTimer = setInterval(function() {
  change_price.text(Math.floor(Math.random() * (100-50+1)) + 50);
}, 100);
```

```css
#myprice {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size:24px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myprice">50</div>
```

Comment: please add the function to your post too, `getRandomIntInclusive`

Comment: @hanshenrik For this question only need this part of function so i removed additional code

Comment: @Mohammad I can see that the most generated numbers are above 50, but I am still getting numbers under 50 too.

Comment: @Bill that means you did not do it as in this answer. Run the snippet -- there is never a value below 50.

Comment: @Bill Check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abckopdz/) if number is below 50 color changed to red

Comment: Thank you both. I just checked again and it work like it should.